# delete data with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am unable to delete records from database, fetching code is working but delete code is not working. please help me out.. thanks in advance

**code to fetch data with ajax**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        done();
    });
    function done(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            updates();
            done();
            }, 200);
    }

    function updates(){
        $.getJSON("fetch.php",function(data){
            $("table").empty();
            $("table").append("<tr><td>Name</td><td>Date</td><td>Delete</td></tr>");
            $.each(data.result, function(){
                $("table").append("<tr><td>"+this['text']+"</td><td>"+this['date']+"</td><td><a id='del' href='"+this['id']+"'>Del</a></td></tr>");
            });
        });
    }
```

**code to delete data with ajax**

```
        $(function() {
    $("#del").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var id = element.attr("id");
    var dataString = 'id=' + id;
    if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this comment?"))
    {
       $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "del.php",
       data: dataString,
       success: function(){

            }
         });
    }
    return false;
    });

});
```

**php code del.php**

```
$last_page_id = $_REQUEST['d_i_d'];
$sql = mysql_query("delete from time where id = '{$last_page_id}'");

if(!$sql){
    echo mysql_error();
}else{
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: We will need the php code of the del.php page to help you.

Comment: Post code in `del.php` also

Comment: Ever thought the problem may lie in your SQL? as an and/or?

Comment: del.php code also dude

Comment: For adequate work elements ID must be unique. Moreover, for dynamically created elemets use delegated event handlers.

Comment: no, from the jQuery ajax page: `data -> Type: PlainObject or String or Array`

Comment: @Robin Sir i uploaded the php code please guide me.. thx

Comment: `$_REQUEST['d_i_d']` <= right there, do `id` and not `d_i_d`. As per => `var dataString = 'id=' + id;`

Comment: Also keep in mind that it would be a cleaner solution if delete is not done with GET. GET should be idempotent.

Comment: BTW -> mysql_query is deprecated, use  MySQLi or PDO_MySQL.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sir i did not understand where i will do the changes.. please elaborate that area,,, thx

Comment: @Mani change `$_REQUEST['d_i_d']` to `$_REQUEST['id']`

Comment: @Fred-ii- sir Object not found! this error i m getting...

Comment: @GuyT The docs sais something different... Type: PlainObject or String or Array. It's not wrong to change it to an object (it's more readable) but it's not the issue...

Comment: Did you try to use a var dump on php side to see what is returned ?

Comment: @lolka_bolka I wasn't aware of that, but his parameter is obviously wrong(like Fred -ii- already mentioned.

Comment: @GuyT: that's ok, i've just want to be sure, OP and others who will see the comments wont learn that the data should be always object.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax data:     `dataString = 'id=' + id;`

calling it in php:    `$last_page_id = $_REQUEST['d_i_d'];`

You can get the id with `$_REQUEST['id']`

Please note that mysql_ is deprecated: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

And that your code is open to SQL injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I said that [`5 minutes prior to this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465335/delete-data-with-ajax#comment41568714_26465335) waiting on OP's response.

Comment: [`Now you see why`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465335/delete-data-with-ajax#comment41568982_26465335) I use comments first to make sure.

Comment: Lol, got a point there. Noticing the obvious mistake made me overlook the other error. However, It just took me 5 min to get the links in the article (had to look them up) so basically we were answering the same answer only through a different method, I was not copying your comment.

Comment: Not a problem. Whenever I feel that something may not be clear or using a comment may only partially solve a problem, I will use the commments box first, just to be certain. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass data like this:

```
$.ajax{
    url: 'del.php',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
        id: // Put your ID value here
    }
    success: function(){
        // Put your success code here
    }
}
```

Look that fragment:

```
$("#del").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var id = element.attr("id");
...
```

`id` variable will always hold "del" value, because you get ID attr of $('#del').

Comment: sir my this line of code is ok.... please guide me
<a id='del' href='"+this['id']+"'>Del</a>

Comment: The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) sais something different... `Type: PlainObject or String or Array` I don't say it's wrong but it is not the issue :)

Comment: Passing as object or string is not the issue, but the part about alweays sending "del" value is true. @Mani on that html you should use `.attr('href')`

Comment: `$('#del').click(function(){`
`var target = $(this).attr('href');`
`...`

Now you can pass `target` variable as `id` in `data`.